# OneDrive - Share is missing password or expiration date or additional features

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, onedrive, sharing

I saw a YouTube video where it shows I can setup additional options when sharing a file. These options are missing.

I am on free personal OneDrive. please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting expiration date and password is not supported using personal OneDrive account comes with free Microsoft account.

You have to buy a Premium subscription (Microsoft 365 Family or Microsoft 365 Personal) for these.

[image]

---

> With a Microsoft 365 subscription, you can add expiration dates and passwords to files you share in OneDrive to make them more secure.

**Source**: [Use expiration dates and passwords](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-your-data-safe-87f64a1b-4019-41bb-aab9-c39ccf4de120)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) if my post helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.